# is there variable holds the distro name/id in yum repo config file?

Tags: yum

there is $releasever can be use to identify version. But I host a repo contain both fedora and centos rpms. If there is variable holdsthe distro name/id I can then use a uniform yum repo conf.

Comment: Why do you have a repo with rpms from two distros? That's a nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: well, I only have single server so they are sit on same server with different path

Comment: Short answer - No, there is not.

Comment: It's a terrible idea to have a repo with packages from two distros. You can and will effectively put a system into dependency hell by having them install incompatible packages.

Comment: @NasirRiley no one try to use repo from different distro. I simple asked ways to unify the repo conf. So `xxx/$distro/$releasever` can expand to `xx/CentOS/7` or `xx/Fedora/33` respectively according to where the xx.repo file sits on.

Comment: That's exactly what you're doing. You stated in your question that you host a repo that contains rpms from both Fedora and CentOS. Those are two different distros. With the way that you have it, it's possible for a Fedora user to pull CentOS rpms and for a CentOS user to pull Fedora rpms. A better way to do this is to make a different repo for Fedora and CentOS. You could have done that many times over in the time that you've been waiting for an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the man page `man yum.conf`, section VARIABLES.  There is no variable doing exactly what you want, as fpmurphy has pointed out.

You could perhaps use shell variables `YUM0` through `YUM9` but you would need to set them locally per machine. They would also need to be set by any process like the yum cron job.

Any machine also has a (unique) UUID set in `$uuid` so you could create a folder for the two build targets, then add symbolic links for each UUID of client machines to point to the relevant folder.

You can find out what the UUID is by using it in a yum repo address of your own, then checking the server access logs.

Answer (score 0):

For a full dump you can use:
`$ yum config-manager --dump`  or  `$ dnf config-manager --dump`

To dump variables you can use: 
`$ yum config-manager --dump-variables`  or  `$ dnf config-manager --dump-variables`

`yum-config-manager` is also available but typically redirects to the DNS config-manager Plugin

From https://linux.die.net/man/5/yum.conf:

$releasever This will be replaced with the value of the version of
the package listed in distroverpkg. This defaults to the version of
'redhat-release' package.

Files
/etc/yum.conf
/etc/yum.repos.d/
/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/
/etc/yum/protected.d
/etc/yum/vars